# operator does not exist: bit & integer

Tags: postgresql

I ran the following in psql to flip a bit:

```
select (b'11' & ~0)
```

but received this error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bit & 
integer
LINE 1: select (b'11' & ~0);
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: To perform the bitwise AND operation, operands must be of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that both operands are of the same type, bit or integer. Here's an example:

**Using bit operands:**

```
SELECT (B'11'::bit & ~B'0'::bit);
```

**Using integer operands:**

```
SELECT (3 & ~0);
```

Choose what is better suite for you